# On Button click event - no form data

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I've a form with `textboxes`, `dropdownlists` & a `button`. I had to use`UseSubmitBehavior = "false"` for `postback`. This I had never used before, but `OnClick` event wasn't firing at all without adding this feature `UseSubmitBehavior = "false"`.

Now when the postback is happening, I'm unable to get any of the controls data i.e. `textboxes` & `dropdownlists` under `button click event`

I wasted my entire day to find `UseSubmitBehavior` and now another problem. Please guide me, what could be wrong.

Comment: I'm quite curious as to why u need to use UseSubmitBehaviour? That will probably point to the root cause of your problems. Maybe you can share relevant code or html?

Answer (score -1):

Update your button code:

```
Button button = new Button();
queryButton.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
button .ID = "btnSubmit";
button .Text = "Submit";
button .Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
Controls.Add(button );
```

Then, write the click event handler: (to call click event that was not fired)

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Your Code 
}
```

Comment: As stated in my question, with UseSubmitBehavior I do get the postback now... But inside this event, I dont get any form data, i.e. textbox or dropdownlist data's

Comment: will you tell that are you able to get this text box id or not ?

Comment: I used UseSubmitBehavior = "false" for a button and i am able to get text box data on click event

Comment: Debug your code are you able to enter inside the `postback` condition block ? if you are using like this 'if `if (!IsPostBack)` then this block's logic will not call,on every button click. so use `if(IsPostBack)`